# How to create custom JWT token using user defined model?

Tags: php, laravel-5

i had developed JWT web token based laravel 5.3 project. Now i was struggled in authentication process because i have create new model like UserAccountsModel and also controller was different.The problem is token not generating. Here is my code

```
    $credentials['Email']       = $request->get('username');
    $credentials['Password']    = $request->get('password');

    try {
        if (! $token = JWTAuth::attempt($credentials)) {
            return response()->json(['error' => 'invalid_credentials'], 401);
        }
    } catch (JWTException $e) {
        return response()->json(['error' => 'could_not_create_token'], 500);
    }

    // if no errors are encountered we can return a JWT
    return response()->json(compact('token'));
```

its only returning invalid_credentials..

so please any one can tell me where will i struggled and what are the configuration i am missing.